# How can a non-sine waveform can equate to combination of DC voltage?

Tags: waveform

> It has been found that any repeating, non-sinusoidal waveform can be equated to a combination of DC voltage, sine waves, and/or cosine waves (sine waves with a 90 degree phase shift) at various amplitudes and frequencies.

Above excerpt from allaboutcircuits.com. 
I understand that a non-sine wave can be broken down into a combination of harmonic sine waves. What I dont understand is how it states above that it can also be from DC voltage which isnt alternating like a sine wave.

Could someone help clarify? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not in the scope of SO.

Comment: Please advise where i can post this type of question.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ looks promising. See https://stackexchange.com/sites